# Finding all of the element in a product group

Tags: group-theory

I would like to find all of the element in the following group: $U_n\times \mathbb Z_n$ when $U_n$ is the Multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the Sum group of integers modulo.

For example, How can I find part or all of the element in $U_{10}\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$?

Comment: What is your definition of the direct product? Tuples with componentwise group operation or via the universal property?

Comment: @Luke thanks for the reply. The definition is $G\times H = \{(g,h)|g\in G,h\in H\}$

Comment: That is a set, and not yet a group. How is the multiplication defined?

Answer (score 0):

$U_{10}\oplus \mathbb Z_{10}\cong \mathbb Z_{4}\oplus \mathbb Z_{10}$

Can you do now?